# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' - CONVOKIT

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I am working with [this](https://zissou.infosci.cornell.edu/convokit/documentation/persuasionforgood.html?fbclid=IwAR1eCL6LjixUb9rjQiqT19Zc52gDBrSfP44oL8w2mdFbc4DuGTQmr1KuXxk) dataset.

When I try:

```
from convokit import Corpus, User, Utterance

corpus_users = {k: User(name=k, meta=v) for k,v in user_meta_dict.items()}
```

I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Comment: It should be `User(owner=k, meta=v)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **init** function of the class User takes as parameter:

```
 owner=None,
 id: str = None,
 utts=None,
 convos=None,
 meta: Union[Dict, NoneType] = None
```

so since name is not a Parameter of the function User you get this kind of error

Comment: when I changed "name" to "owner" everything works but now I get: ````AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'meta_index'````